# Wiring up the code behind of the View with some Action in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

In a Silverlight app that is written with MVVM I want to enable/disable my view based on some stuff.

In the constructor of the View class in code behind I can say something like this and it disables the form:

```
public MyForm1View()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(this.DataContext == null)
    {
       this.IsEnabled = False;
    }
}
```

The issue is when there is no data to load, I am showing a gray overlay screen on top of my form to the user with a link on that gray overlay that says "Create a New Record"....now the problem is that if I disable my form like that above then How can I re-enable it when they click that CreateNewRecord link?

But how can I reenable it again from the view-model? Maybe I should have an Action on my ViewModel and when it's called on the ViewModel, it calls a method that's wired up in the code behind of the View ?  But how to code this idea?

Comment: bind `IsEnabled` property to a property in viewmodel, then you can simply change viewmodel's property to enable View again later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest few things:

simple wrapper for ICommand Interface:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action execute;
        private readonly Func<bool> canExecute;
        public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {

            if (this.canExecute != null)
            {
                return this.canExecute();
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute();
        }

        public void RaiseExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

   public void ViewModel() {
    SwitchCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => this.IsEnabled = true, () => true);
   }

   public DelegateCommand SwitchCommand {get;set;}

   private bool isEnabled;
   public bool IsEnabled {
    get {
      return isEnabled;
    }
    set {
      isEnabled = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
    }

// here, InotifyPropertyChanged implementation, dozens of sample available
}
```

Xaml:

as example:

```
<Button Command={Binding SwitchCommand} />  bind command to click.
```

So, what's left is to set ViewModel to View, via view constructor, of IoC if you use it.

hope that help.